# react-webcam (npm) reset camera

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webcam

I have a very simple basic implementation of [react-webcam npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-webcam).

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import Webcam from "react-webcam";

const ReactWebcam = () => {
  const webcamElement = useRef(null);

  const videoConstraints = {
    width: 640,
    height: 360,
    facingMode: "user",
  };

  const audioConstraints = {
    suppressLocalAudioPlayback: true,
    noiseSuppression: true,
    echoCancellation: true,
  };

  return (
    <div className="webcam" style={{ width: 640 }}>
      <Webcam
        ref={webcamElement}
        audio={false}
        screenshotFormat="image/jpeg"
        videoConstraints={videoConstraints}
        audioConstraints={audioConstraints}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReactWebcam;
```

This all seems to work fine, however if the computer comes out of sleep mode (having closed and re-opened the lid on my laptop for example), the webcam component just displays a black-screen.

I therefore wonder if anyone has any advice on being able to refresh the stream either by a button or a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you need to detect when the user clicks to come back on its browser's tab already opened before.

You need to listen the js event `visibilitychange`

Once you know the user came back on your page, you trigger something to refresh (websocket works like this also).

You can find modules online to do this :

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ifvisible.js
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/visibility-state-listener
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-visibility-change

But I developed mine :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback, FC } from 'react'
import window from 'global/window'

const vendorEvents = [
  {
    hidden: 'hidden',
    event: 'visibilitychange',
    state: 'visibilityState'
  },
  {
    hidden: 'webkitHidden',
    event: 'webkitvisibilitychange',
    state: 'webkitVisibilityState'
  },
  {
    hidden: 'mozHidden',
    event: 'mozvisibilitychange',
    state: 'mozVisibilityState'
  },
  {
    hidden: 'msHidden',
    event: 'msvisibilitychange',
    state: 'msVisibilityState'
  },
  {
    hidden: 'oHidden',
    event: 'ovisibilitychange',
    state: 'oVisibilityState'
  }
]

const isDocumentSupported = typeof document !== 'undefined' && Boolean(document.addEventListener)

export const visibility = (() => {
  if (isDocumentSupported) {
    for (let i = 0; i < vendorEvents.length; i++) {
      const event = vendorEvents[i]
      if (event.hidden in document) {
        return { type: document, event }
      }
    }

    if ('onfocusin' in document) {
      return [
        { type: document, action: 'in', event: 'focusin' },
        { type: document, action: 'out', event: 'focusout' }
      ]
    }
  }

  const responses = []
  if ('onpageshow' in window) {
    responses.push({ type: window, action: 'in', event: 'pageshow' })
    responses.push({ type: window, action: 'out', event: 'pagehide' })
  }
  if ('onfocus' in window) {
    responses.push({ type: window, action: 'in', event: 'focus' })
    responses.push({ type: window, action: 'out', event: 'blur' })
  }

  if (responses.length === 0) {
    return null
  }

  return responses
})()

const usePageVisibility = () => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(true)

  const handler = useCallback(
    (event, action) => {
      if (action !== 'in' && action !== 'out') {
        setIsVisible(action)
      }
      if (action === 'in' && !isVisible) {
        setIsVisible(true)
      }
      if (action === 'out' && isVisible) {
        setIsVisible(false)
      }
    },
    [isVisible]
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    if (visibility) {
      if (Array.isArray(visibility)) {
        visibility.forEach(e => {
          e.type.addEventListener(e.event, event => handler(event, e.action))
        })
      } else {
        visibility.type.addEventListener(visibility.event.event, event => handler(event, !visibility.type[visibility.event.hidden]))
      }
    }
    return () => {
      if (visibility) {
        if (Array.isArray(visibility)) {
          visibility.forEach(e => {
            e.type.removeEventListener(e.event, event => handler(event, e.action))
          })
        } else {
          visibility.type.removeEventListener(visibility.event.event, event => handler(event, !visibility.type[visibility.event.hidden]))
        }
      }
    }
  }, [handler])

  if (!visibility) {
    return true
  }

  return isVisible
}

export default usePageVisibility
```

```
import usePageVisibility from '../../components/VisibilityListeners'

const isVisible = usePageVisibility()
const oldIsVisible = useRef(isVisible)

useEffect(() => {
  if (!isLoading && indexDay !== -1 && isVisible && !oldIsVisible.current) {
    closeWebSocket()
    openWebSocket()
  }
  oldIsVisible.current = isVisible
}, [isVisible, openWebSocket, closeWebSocket, isLoading, indexDay])
```